# OptiX Denoising is making the text in my Render come out blurry. How can I turn down the strength of the denoiser?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, denoise

I have seen this question asked a few times; denoising seems to always blur out finer details in a render, which would be fine, except it blurs out text that I am projecting onto a wall in my scene. I have seen others recommend turning the denoising strength down, but I can't find this option anywhere, and the internet doesn't seem to want to give me the answer with this one. I am using Blender 2.93 (stable), Render Engine Cycles, GPU compute, OptiX denoising. Here is what my settings look like; it seems that on older versions there were options in the denoising tab such as strength etc, but I can't seem to find them on my version.
[image: Blender Render Settings]

I don't know if there's an alternative route to stopping the denoiser from blurring out the text, so I welcome any suggestions!
Thank you so much!

Comment: From the docs: "The denoiser will change in the future and some features are not implemented yet. If denoising fails to produce good results, more samples or clamping will often resolve the issue."

Comment: Ah, I see. I hope they implement the changes soon, but for now, thank you so much for your input. I'll look into clamping and/or more samples...if my computer can take it, that is. Thanks again!